# Get data from inside a link without clicking it and transfer it to a database

Tags: database, hyperlink

Any idea on how do i get data from inside a link without clicking it and transfer it to a database?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by data inside a link?

Comment: @Rachcha - For example the link is a number and has three other numbers inside that link that need to be transferred to a database along with the number on the link in another row.

Comment: Your question is still thoroughly unclear. Where are your numbers- in the URL or the querystring? What web server are you using- PHP, JSP or .Net or some other?